# Model training with tf.data.Dataset and NumPy arrays yields different results

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I use the Keras model training API and observed differences when training the model with NumPy arrays (`x_train` and `y_train`) and with `tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))`. A minimal working example is shown below:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(0)

n_examples, n_dims = (100, 10)
raw_dataset = np.random.randn(n_examples, n_dims)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            1024, activation="relu", use_bias=True
        ),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            1, activation="linear", use_bias=True
        ),
    ]
)

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss="mse",
)

x_train = raw_dataset[:, :-1]
y_train = raw_dataset[:, -1]
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))

n_epochs = 10
batch_size = 16

use_dataset = True
if use_dataset:
    model.fit(
        dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size),
        epochs=n_epochs,
    )
else:
    model.fit(
        x=x_train,
        y=y_train,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        epochs=n_epochs,
    )

print("Evaluation:")
model.evaluate(x_train, y_train)
model.evaluate(dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size))
```

If I run this code with `use_dataset = True`, the final performance is:

```
Evaluation:
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 825us/step - loss: 0.4132
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 701us/step - loss: 0.4132
```

If I run it with `use_dataset = False`, I get:

```
Evaluation:
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 855us/step - loss: 0.4219
7/7 [==============================] - 0s 808us/step - loss: 0.4219
```

I expected that the two training loops would perform identically. Interestingly, the model performance is identical if I set `batch_size = n_examples`. The difference seems to be related with the way that batches are handled internally. Why is this happening? Is it a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior is due to the default parameter `shuffle=True` in `model.fit(*)` and not a bug. According to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) regarding `shuffle`:

> Boolean (whether to shuffle the training data before each epoch) or str (for 'batch'). This argument is ignored when x is a generator or an object of tf.data.Dataset. 'batch' is a special option for dealing with the limitations of HDF5 data; it shuffles in batch-sized chunks. Has no effect when steps_per_epoch is not None.

So this parameter is ignored when a `tf.data.Dataset` is passed, and the data is not reshuffled after each epoch as in the other approach with arrays.
Here is the code to get the same results for both methods:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(0)

n_examples, n_dims = (100, 10)
raw_dataset = np.random.randn(n_examples, n_dims)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            1024, activation="relu", use_bias=True
        ),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            1, activation="linear", use_bias=True
        ),
    ]
)

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss="mse",
)

x_train = raw_dataset[:, :-1]
y_train = raw_dataset[:, -1]
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))

n_epochs = 10
batch_size = 16

use_dataset = False
if use_dataset:
    model.fit(
        dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size),
        epochs=n_epochs,
    )
else:
    model.fit(
        x=x_train,
        y=y_train,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        shuffle=False,
        epochs=n_epochs,
    )

print("Evaluation:")
model.evaluate(x_train, y_train)
model.evaluate(dataset.batch(batch_size=batch_size))
```